# Python reversed list

Tags: python

```
newlist="a,b,c"
list2=newlist.split(',')
finalList=list2[:]
```

How can I make this return the reversed list using while?

```
y=len(list2)-1
z=0
finalList[2]='X'
while z < len(list2):
    print(z,y)
    finalList[z]=list2[y]
    y-=1
    z+=1
return finalList
```

Comment: Why not just `finalList = list2[::-1]`...

Comment: Why do you need to use `while`? It makes no sense.

Comment: `finalList = reversed(list2)`

Comment: do you want to use the while loop just for fun/training purposes?